# C# Создается пустой лист в начале документа Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.
Задача: беру шаблон, заполняю его данными, потом полученный лист копирую в другой документ, обнуляю изменения шаблона, опять заполняю и так в цикле до выполнения некоторых условий. Т.е. задача на выходе иметь 1 документ с множеством заполненных по шаблону листов.
Реализовал код, но проблема в том, что итоговый файл начинается с полностью пустого листа. Включил отображение спецсимволов, увидел, что в самом начале документа идет разрыв страницы. Не понимаю что его порождает и как его убрать.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
//
Application wordApp = new Application(); // Word
Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Add(@"C:\\template.docx"); //Документ с шаблоном и закладками
Document docfull = new Document(); //Финальный документ
docfull = wordApp.Documents.Add(); //Создаю пустой лист в новом документе

//Тут идет блок действий по заполнению шаблона через закладки
//<...>
//

//Дальше заполненный лист шаблона объекта doc я вставляю в документ docfull и так в цикле вставляю несколько листов чтобы получить единый документ

//БАГ происходит где-то здесь! Первый лист документа пустой из-за того что содержит разрыв страницы
foreach (Section section in doc.Sections)
{
     Section newSections = docfull.Sections.Add();
     section.Range.Copy();
     newSections.Range.Paste();
}

docfull.SaveAs2(@"C:\\test.docx");
docfull.Close(false);
doc.Close(false);
wordApp.Quit();
```

Comment: В общем пока нашел только костыль. 
Перед сохранением файла делаю docfull.Sections[1].Range.Delete();
Но на мой взгляд это опасно)